# Direct call of a method vs Method overloading

Tags: java, performance, oop, overloading

I am curious to know what is better: method overloading or direct call of a method?

Here is the example of direct method call:

```
public class A {
    public void method(String arg, String[] paramNames, String[] paramValues) {
        // do something with arg taking into consideration paramNames and paramValues
    }
}

public class B {
    public void meth() {
         A a = new A();
         a.method("some string", new String[] {"paramName"}, new String[] {"paramValue"});
         a.method("some other string", new String[] {""}, new String[] {""});
    }
}
```

And here is the example of method overloading:

```
public class A {
    public void method(String arg, String[] paramNames, String[] paramValues) {
         // do something with arg taking into consideration paramNames and paramValues
    }

    public void method(String arg) {
        method(arg, new String[] {""}, new String[] {""});
    }
}

public class B {
    public void meth() {
        A a = new A();
        a.method("some string", new String[] {"paramName"}, new String[] {"paramValue"});
        a.method("some other string");
    }
}
```

The question is, which option is better regarding OOP, performance, best practices, etc.?

- Probably the first option is faster than the second, regarding that the later option has more push/pops to *activation record stack*, which will slow down the program execution, but does that really matter?
- On the other hand, the second approach seems to be more cleaner and nicer regarding OOP.

**EDIT:** Let's consider that `method(String arg)` is being called 1 000 000 000 000 times and even more, wouldn't there be a performance issue in that case, since it calls `method(String arg, String[] paramNames, String[] paramValues)` internally?

Comment: option 2 is commonly used by overloading constructors....

Comment: There won't be any performance difference. Favor the solution that is the most readable, and most importantly, that is the safer. The first one would force every caller to remember that it needs to pass a single-element array containing an empty string as argument. That is far from being obvious (and is quite unnatural, BTW. Why not pass an empty array, or better, an empty List).

Comment: IMHO this question is way off from real life. What is better regarding "OOP" is entirely open to debate, and which one is faster is heavily depending on what the JIT will do (especially if it is invocated  1 000 000 000 000 times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 2**

Option 1 will take a little less time (negligible). *However,* overloading is much easier to read, and overall a better practice (for testing, etc.)

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Java is pass-by-value, meaning the JVM makes a copy of each parameter value and gives those copies to the method. Thus, if the method is called  1 000 000 000 000 times, yes, there will be a performance difference for sure.

Comment: No, Java is pass-by-reference for anything other than primitives.

Comment: Java passes the value of variables; for primitives this is a copy of the byte sequence it represents, while for variables containing a reference to an object it is precisely that reference, not a copy of the object. The reference is the value of the variable. Hence, Java is pass by value.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the other answers the performance impact is negligible. Especially if the overloaded method is called very often the Java JIT compiler will inline the method call making both calls exactly the same.

Overloading is best practice and should be used, if the alternative method is expected to be used frequently. You should however not provide overloaded alternatives for each possible edge case, as this would pollute your API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a performance overhead due to overloading as Java knows which function to use. And it knows that too at compile time way before execution. And when it knows what to do before execution there cannot be any performance overheads.

So there should not be any performance overheads at all.
Also, function overloading is an OOP concept. Hence it is much better to use function overloading -> that is basically the essence of OOPs. I will say to use function overloading! (y) :)

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would always recommend the second approach. It is much easy to maintain and to refactor if required. Not sure about speed, however, in the first case the actual code of `method` would most likely have quite a few branches to provide logic for cases when one or more parameters are missing. Those branches will take time.

EDIT: I see here some similarities with Interface Segregation Principle (if we consider method's header as some sort of interface to it's contents).

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference Method overloading is used to provide alternatives to the user. For example if you just provide one method to add to numbers, user would not have any alternatives i.e to add 3 or more numbers. On the other hand Method overloading provides alternatives.
You may want to give the user only one method with the name "Add" but you want to provide option to add 2 numbers or 3 numbers like

```
public int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

public int add(int a, int b, int c){
    return a+b+c;
}
```

So you can say Method overloading provides flexibility and alternatives to the user.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: See this one I hope it answers what you're asking
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875136/can-nested-function-or-method-call-reduce-performance-of-application